# Ensure that all relevant elections details are available on all screen sizes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, election, responsive-design

[Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) is running an [election](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/election) at the moment.

Users that log into …/elections from devices with differently-sized screens get vastly different levels of information regarding the procedures and rules.

For users who use the **full site view**, either from a regular computer or by disabling responsiveness, get this:

[image]

The instructions include details on voting rules, service provider, counting modalities and a link to get the detailed results after the elections.

Users with **mobile-sized screens** on the responsive view (*not* the deprecated mobile-web view) see a very rudimentary version, absent of the entire blue dialogue and all instructions. All they get is the meta-information from above the horizontal rule on the full version:

[image]

There’s a promising “learn more” link, but that just gives a pop-up window which is also sorely lacking:

[image]

While it’s understandable that a pared-down view of the site on small devices is practical in daily use, I believe that **for elections, users should be given equal information and equal access to resources**. Access to the full information should not depend upon a user experimentally disabling responsiveness.

---

Pictures are screenshots from an iPhone 8 / iOS 14.8. First with responsiveness disabled, the latter two with responsiveness enabled.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wBeo.jpg responsive is clearly active.... Its even worse in my phone... Android 11 and chrome 94

Comment: Oddly enough, this only happens for me on the "Election" tab and not the "Nomination" or "Primary" tabs. Is it the same for you?

Comment: @Medix2 Nomination and primary seem ok to me.

Comment: @JNat Wanted to verify: was this marked [status-deferred] because it seemed to be about the old mobile view? Or was it understood that this is happening in the _responsive view on mobile-sized screens_? Just want to be sure it didn't get tossed aside because it appeared to be about [mobile-web] at first.

Comment: It was understood that it was about the responsive view on mobile, yes, @zcoop98

Comment: @zcoop98 my extremely looooong screenshot was meant to make sure that was clear beyond question :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The election stage info box now shows up properly on narrow-width screens.

> Responsive pages
> are fun in ways one never
> would have considered